# Wrap React component with another component in the same file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a `Button` and `Hovered` component. The hovered component holds state and mouseover events and will pass down `hovered` props to its children. The button is a normal button.

I want to be able to access the hovered value as a prop on the Button, but I don't want to have to wrap the Button with Hovered everywhere that I use it.

**Is there a way a wrapping the Button component in the same `Button.jsx` file so that I can keep the Hovered dependency in one place, but still get the props passed down?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to wrap the component with something like this:

```
//Button.jsx

var Button = React.createClass({
    //Stuff
});

function Hoverify(Component) {
  var Hoverified = React.createClass({
    //HOVER STUFF HERE
    render() {
      return <Component {...this.props} {...this.state} />;
    }
  });
  return Hoverified;
};


module.exports = Hoverify(Button);
```

Put the `Hoverify` stuff in a seperate file for maximum reuse.

Alternatively, if you prefer inheritence, you can also do something like this via ES6/7 classes:

```
export default class Hover extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.onMouseOver = this.onMouseOver.bind(this);
  }

  //hove functions and such
  onMouseOver(){
     console.log("look ma, I hovered");
  }
}

export default class Button extends Hover {
   constructor(){
     super();
   }
}
```